# Magento 2.1 Admin Category Page Shows Blank (500 Internal Server Error)

Tags: magento-2.1

Its quite strange error. I have been working around with Magento 2 since a while now, and I am not sure what went wrong here. Navigating to the following tab on admin:

*Product -> Categories*

Return a plain empty page. When checked on Network Tab, it shows Internal Server Error with status 500. All the other admin pages are working perfectly fine.

Any help would really be appreciated.

Comment: Go to app/bootstrap.php file remove comment from `ini_set(display_errors,1);` then flush cache and check again it will show error.